# Preallocating for a loop with several variables

Tags: matlab

I am running a loop that takes data from cells in a table and adds them to a structure. Here is exactly what it looks like:

```
TotalLowResfields = fieldnames(TotalLowRes);

for t = 10:numel(TotalLowResfields)

    rows = {TotalLowRes.c};
    cols = [TotalLowRes.y] - 10 + t;
    subtable = Raw(rows, cols);

    values = table2cell(subtable);
    values = values(logical(eye(numel(rows))));

    [TotalLowRes.(TotalLowResfields{t})] = deal(values{:});
end
```

It takes almost 7 minutes to run through this loop and I want to preallocate to increase speed.

I tried preallocating:

```
subtable = zeros(1828,1828);
values = zeros(1828,1);
```

It didn't help much. It took 404 seconds before preallocation and it takes 403 seconds after.
The struct array I am working with, `TotalLowRes`, has 1828 structs in it and there are 29 fields so it goes through 19 fields of 1828 structs = 34732 entries. But how do I preallocate the struct if it is even possible?

**Edit:** I ran the profiler and this is what it shows:

```
Function Name                 Calls   Total Time   Self Time
able2cell                     19        362.585 s    1.838 s  
mat2cell                      34732     360.747 s    360.747 s
table.subsrefParens           19        66.066 s     0.720 s
table.subsref                 19        66.066 s     0.000 s 
makeUniqueStrings             38        64.887 s     0.003 s 
makeUniqueStrings>makeUnique  38        64.258 s     63.960 s
```

It seems that functions `mat2cell` and `makeUniqueStrings>makeUnique` are the most expensive ones. Is there a way to minimize calculation times for them?

Comment: (1) I'd try the profiler first to see what's taking so long. `profile on` then run your code, then `profile off` and finally `profile viewer` (2) I love table, but for high performance, some calls to table aren't fast...

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thank you for the tip! I added the profile to my question

Comment: From the profiler results I would guess you are using very large tables? How large is the table and how many rows/cols do you really index? Maybe you can improve your code example initializing the variables with some random data of the right size.

Comment: @Daniel The `subtable` table appears to be 1828 x 1828 = 3341584. That might be considered large. I preallocated `subtable = zeroes(1828,1828) ` before the loop but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov: Preallocation won't help here. The time is spend within the function call `table2cell` which for some reason calls `mat2cell` a lot of times. If preallocation would be an issue, you would be a large "Self Time" for your function.

Comment: @Daniel Would the only way to make it faster be to rewrite the code and do it another way?

Comment: @ArthurTarasov: Yes. I assume directly indexing the diagonal (maybe using `sub2ind`) would be faster, but I can not test it because my Matlab Version is to old to support `table`

Comment: Is it not an option to transform `Raw` once (or twice) into a cell, then accessing subsets of those elements later on?